# Did the souls in the keywork interact with each other before Sirius arrived?

Tags: souls, amory-wars

In the Amory Wars, the souls of the deceased are sent to power the Keywork. When a living man, Sirius, enters the Keywork, the souls attempt to possess him.

While Sirius is still in the keywork, two souls named Vic and Sentry fight with each other after first possessing Sirius.

My question, is there any evidence that any of the souls interacted before Sirius' arrival or did his arrival trigger the interaction between the souls?

Here's the wikipedia reference to the story I'm referring to - I have a feeling not many are going to be familiar with it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amory_Wars#The_Afterman

Comment: I'm kind of surprised there aren't more questions about the Amory Wars on here!

Comment: Thought I'd get it started. I have several other questions but I didn't want to spam stackexchange. :]

Comment: @Monty129 - Have you read this series?